# Why doesn't pyusb detect any usb devices?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyusb

when I run the code

```
import usb
devices = list(usb.core.find(find_all=True))
print(devices)
```

the program only outputs a [], although devices are connected via usb.
need help

I just wanted it to spit out a list of found usb devices

Answer (score 0):

That's quite difficult to guess which is your problem without more context :(

You could try using [USBMonitor](https://pypi.org/project/usb-monitor/) to get the connected devices, which is based in [pyudev](https://pyudev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)/[wmi](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32), depending on the operating system you are running. If it returns something, it will probably mean that your problem had something to do with low-level drivers. But that's difficult to know.

To install the library

```
pip install usb-monitor
```

Then you can run

```
from usbmonitor import USBMonitor

# Get a dictionary with all the connected USB devices
available_devices = USBMonitor().get_available_devices()
```